# How could SSL certificate affect the symmetric key length?

Tags: tls, key-exchange

[This article](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/848/what-is-the-encryption-strength-of-your-ssl-certificates) in GoDaddy support knowledge base says

> All of our SSL certificates support high-grade 256-bit encryption

How would they not support it?

The SSL certificate contains keys for ***asymmetric*** encryption and is there to

1. prove that the server is exactly what it claims and
2. allow the server and the client choose the same ***symmetric*** encryption key which is then used for the rest of the connection

It looks like nothing prevents the client and the server from negotiating some MagicAES with 10240-bit key (or 90th level DES with 4096-bit key) and use it for the life of the connection.

How would the SSL certificate internals limit the symmetric key length?

Answer (score 2):

It is, to put it bluntly, a steaming pile of bullshit.

The SSL certificate has no bearing on which SSL or TLS cipher suites are negotiated. The two parts of the protocol are separate.